# GSON / How to parse a number

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse JSON-documents with GSON. However, I have a problem with numbers.

My pattern is simply iterating over all tokens... that is first peeking and then doing stuff based on the TokenType in a switch-statement. The `reader` in the following code snippet is a `JsonReader`.

```
while (reader.hasNext() && !endReached) {
  final var nextToken = reader.peek();

  switch (nextToken) {
    case NUMBER:
      // reader.nextInt(), reader.nextLong(), reader.nextDouble()
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I know if it's an Integer/Long or a decimal value, maybe only fitting into a BigDecimal? Just calling nextString() and then try to parse the String with BigDecimal and so on?

Answer (score 1):

In [JSON](https://www.json.org/), numbers are always floating-point numbers of the form
`['-'] digits [ '.' digits ] [ 'e' sign digits ]`

So basically a `double`, except `NaN` and `±Infinity`.

For generic code use `nextDouble()`, unless you expect very large numbers, where `BigDecimal` needs to be used.

The `nextInt()` and `nextLong()` method are helper methods for when you know the number is supposed to be an integer value.

Comment: Yeah, I'm developing an open source temporal storage system where I also represent a number as either integer, long, float, double or even BigInteger/BigDecimal (for the new binary and in-memory JSON format). For importing a JSON document it would be nice to get the "most fitting" type of the number :-)

Comment: @Johannes Then use `BigDecimal`, then use `precision()` and `scale()` and maybe `longValueExact()` / `intValueExact()` to determine if the value fits in a `double` / `long` / `int` / `BigInteger`.

Comment: Getting the value as a String first and then parsing as a BigDecimal? The value I expect is a "Number", this abstract class and internally I'm making instance of checks for the precise type which is a bit ugly, but yeah.